# Sufficient Statistic for the beta distribution with one fixed shape parameter

Tags: self-study, beta-distribution, sufficient-statistics

How can I show that the geometric mean $( \prod_{i=1}^{n} x_i  )^{1/n}$ of a random sample of size $n$ from a distribution with pdf $f(x;\theta)=\theta x^{\theta-1},0<x<1,$, zero elsewhere, and $\theta>0$ is a sufficient statistic for $\theta$?

By the Factorization Theorem we can see that:

$$\prod_{i=1}^{n} f(x_i;\theta)=\theta^n \left[ \prod_{i=1}^n x_i \right]^{\theta-1} $$ and therefore $\prod x_i$ is a sufficient statistic for $\theta$. Now, I know that sufficient statistics are not unique and thus one does not exclude the other.

This distribution is an exponential family, which means its density can be rewritten as:

$$ \exp \{n\log\theta +(\theta-1) \sum \log x_i \}$$

but afterwards, in order to arrive at the geometric mean, there seems to be some subtle manipulation that I am missing.

Comment: Hint: Based on your last formula, it looks like the only way in which the data enter into the likelihood is via the expression $\sum\log x_i$.  How is that related to the geometric mean?

Comment: Almost: you are moving between exponentials and logs too quickly and have mixed them up, but you have the right idea.

Comment: Exchange the position of the two power-coefficients to obtain the geometric mean -you could have done that without using the "exponential class" route.

Comment: What does this have to do with the beta distribution?

Comment: @NeilG Maybe because $f(x;\theta)=\theta x^{\theta-1},0<x<1$ is the beta density? I don't know, I am just spitballing here.

Comment: It's the beta density with one parameter fixed, so it's a curved exponential family.  The sufficient statistics of the beta density are $\log x$ and $\log (1-x)$, so wording your question this way is confusing.

Comment: It is the beta density anyway so please stop editing my question, it's perfectly understood as it is and people have already helped me.